# Can't run "compgen -c" from perl script

Tags: bash, perl, command, redhat

I want to check if a command exists on my machine (RedHat) inside a perl script.

Im trying to check if `compgen -c` contains the desired command, but running it from inside a script just gives me an empty output. Other commands work fine.

example.pl:

```
my $x = `compgen -c`;
print $x;
# empty output

my $y = `ls -a`;
print $y;
# .
# ..
# example.pl
```

Are there possible solutions for this? Or is there a better way to check for commands on my machine?

Comment: @noah : Why don't you run the code explicitly using bash? I don't know what shell `perl` is using by default; could be a compilation option when making the perl binary. And, at least during debugging, I would also catch the stderr of your backtick expression.

Comment: Another point to research is, whether `compgen` works in a non-interactive bash as well. The bash man-page seems to be silent to this point, but for me, it would be logical not to offer any completions in the non-interactive case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Perl runs external commands using `/bin/sh`, which is nowadays a link to a shell that is a default-of-sorts on your system.  Much of the time that is `bash`, but not always; on RedHat it is.

This [`compgen` is a bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html). One way to discover that is to run `man compgen` (in bash) -- and the `bash` manual pops up.  Another way is `type` as Dave shows.

To use builtins we generally need to run an explicit shell for them, and they have a varied behavior in regards to whether the shell is "[interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html)" or not.<sup>†</sup> I can't find a discussion of that in bash documentation for this builtin but experimentation reveals that you need

```
my @completions = qx(bash -c "compgen -c")
```

The quotes are needed so to pass a complete command to a shell that will be started.

Note that this way you don't catch any `STDERR` out of those commands.  That will come out on the terminal, and it can get missed that way. Or, you can redirect that stream in the command, by adding `2>&1` (redirect to `STDOUT`) at the end of it.

This is one of the reasons to use one of a number of good libraries for running and managing external commands instead of the builtin "backticks" (the [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) I use above is an operator form of it.)

---

<sup>†</sup> This can be facilitated with `-i`

```
my @output_lines = qx(bash -i -c "command with arguments")
```

Comment: Some suitable libraries: `Capture::Tiny` and `IPC::Run`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `compgen` is a `bash` built-in command, not an external command. And when you run a command using backticks, you get your system's default shell - which is probably going to be `/bin/sh`, not `bash`.

The solution is to explicitly run `bash`, using the `-c` command-line option to give it a command to run.

```
my $x = `bash -c compgen -c`;
```

From a `bash` prompt, you can use `type` to see how a command is implemented.

```
$ type ssh
ssh is /usr/bin/ssh

$ type compgen
compgen is a shell builtin
```